# MS SQL Server: "Concatenate" tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

## Toy Example

I don't really want to concatenate (i.e., I don't want to merge strings), but if I say `JOIN` it will confuse people.

I have 2 tables that I **know** are properly aligned by row.  I simply want to take the 2 tables and *join* them, but not **on** anything, and I don't want to `CROSS JOIN` or anything similar.  Let me explain by example:

table 1:

```
name    |  city
--------|-----------
Phillip | Chicago
Sarah   | London
```

table 2:

```
phone        | email
-------------|-------
312-241-7754 | pchitown@me.com
+011-11-1111 | slondres@me.com
```

I **know** that these rows match.  That is, the first row of each table refers to `Phillip` and the second row of each table refers to `Sarah`.  But I don't have any shared thing to join ***on***.

---

## Question

I simply want to say something like:

```
INSERT INTO table3
(SELECT * FROM table1 ??CONCATENATE?? table2)
```

where that funny `??CONCATENATE??` is my magical function that simply says "align row 1 of each table together, then row 2, then row 3, etc." so that it looks like:

```
name    |  city    | phone        | email
--------|----------|--------------|-----------------
Phillip | Chicago  | 312-241-7754 | pchitown@me.com
Sarah   | London   | +011-11-1111 | slondres@me.com
```

I'm sure there must be a function to do this, but after searching for a while still couldn't find anything.

Comment: could u edit the question with desired result upon your example ?

Comment: What do you mean by: _"I don't want to `CROSS JOIN` or anything similar."_? What are your requirements?

Comment: `I have 2 tables that I know are properly aligned by row.` I think you might be making at least one incorrect assumption here and while you might find a solution that works for you here (e.g. using a row number window function and ordering by `(select null)` or something like that), there's no _guarantee_ you will always get the same order if you are not specifying an order... Take a quick read of point 3 in this link for a bit of elaboration on this: https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/t-sql-tuesday-56-sql-server-assumptions/

Comment: **I have 2 tables that *I know are properly aligned* by row.** I don't think that would work like that.

Comment: Tried copying and pasting select * into Excel?

Comment: There is no benefit to having 2 tables in this scene. All you achieve by this is an absurd level of unnecessary complexity. It should be one table of 4 columns instead of 2 tables of 2 columns.

Comment: Without an `order by`, the order the rows are returned in is arbitrary. You need a piece of data in the table that indicates which row the data is. Then the solution is trivial - you use a `JOIN`. You can always generate this piece of data on the fly with a `ROW_NUMBER` function, but then the result is also arbitrary

Comment: There are only 2 ways to 'concatenate' tables in sql - join or union(all) and unless you have an identity column (or some other unique incrementing field) on both tables you will not get a meaningful outcome from either.

Comment: @YogeshSharma Yes, good point.  Done!  (I thought I had... I think I was getting tired.)

Comment: @Used_By_Already Yes, I know!  Precisely!  I have inherited those tables.  I want to combine them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Achieve This by Using Row_Number().
But I will better If you Use Primary And Foreign Key Relation Between The 2 Tables

```
BEGIN TRAN

CREATE TABLE #table1(NAME NVARCHAR(50),city NVARCHAR(50))
CREATE TABLE #table2(phone NVARCHAR(50),email NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #table1
SELECT 'Phillip','Chicago' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Sarah','London'


INSERT INTO #table2
SELECT '312-241-7754','pchitown@me.com' UNION ALL
SELECT '+011-11-1111','slondres@me.com'

SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY NAME)Rownum INTO #T1 FROM #table1
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY email)Rownum INTO #T2 FROM #table2

SELECT NAME, City,Phone, Email
FROM #T1 INNER JOIN #T2 ON #t1.Rownum= #t2.Rownum

ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I wanted!  For all those who commented "this is a bad idea", etc., please realize that we inherit what we inherit.  I am not contemplating, as a long term solution, joining tables without primary keys.  But sometimes we gotta put on a band-aid short term...

Comment: Whoever is deciding on the band aids should understand that the result of this is not reliable. If the first table gets a record `Philip Chicagox`then that will be matched to the email

Answer (score 0):

select tb1.name ,tb1.city,tb2.phone,tb2.email from (select *,row_number() over(order by (SELECT NULL))as rno from table1)tb1 inner join  (select *,row_number() over(order by (SELECT NULL))as rno from table2)tb2 on tb1.rno =tb2.rno

Answer (score -1):

Hi I have modified little bit above Alfaiz Ahmed coding

```
BEGIN TRAN

CREATE TABLE #table1(ID INT IDENTITY, NAME NVARCHAR(50),city NVARCHAR(50))
CREATE TABLE #table2(ID INT IDENTITY, phone NVARCHAR(50),email NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #table1
SELECT 'Phillip','Chicago' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Sarah','London'


INSERT INTO #table2
SELECT '312-241-7754','pchitown@me.com' UNION ALL
SELECT '+011-11-1111','slondres@me.com'

SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY NAME)Rownum INTO #T1 FROM #table1
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY email)Rownum INTO #T2 FROM #table2

SELECT NAME, City,Phone, Email
FROM #T1 INNER JOIN #T2 ON #t1.ID = #t2.ID

ROLLBACK TRAN
```